# Apache ProxyPass does not works as expected

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following configuration in httpd.conf

```
ProxyPass /chat http://localhost:8888
```

If I hit the url `localhost/chat/test`, instead of redirecting to `http://localhost:8888/test`, it redirects to `http://localhost:8888`.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ProxyPass /chat http://localhost:8888/test
```

You need to provide project directory folder in this case.